# Feedme plugin: importing tables

Tags: plugin-feedme

Has anybody had issues importing JSON into table fields with the Feedme plugin?

I've got an issue where empty values in my feed are not being parsed into the correct table rows.

Source:

[image: Source JSON]

Result (after import):

[image: result (after import)]

Any thoughts on how best to resolve?

Comment: Per [crawf's answer](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/14284/45), this turned out to be a bug (which has since been fixed).

Answer (score 2):

I'm sure I can give you a hand (Feed Me developer here) - would you be able to submit a Help request using the instructions here - https://github.com/engram-design/FeedMe#support? Happy to post back findings here.

**EDIT:** Thanks for your patience - This was indeed a bug, which has been fixed in the [latest master](https://github.com/engram-design/FeedMe/archive/master.zip).

Let me know if you continue to have issues!

Comment: Hey - submitted through form but on local build so not sure it got through. Will try again …